# Slider Using Scrollbar

Tags: jquery

here is what I am trying to do:

Have a scroll bar with 3 states.

State 1.)  h1 and h2 text and a background color. 
State2.)  h1 and h2 text and a background color. 
State3.)  h1 and h2 text and a background color.

The scrollbar/slider should be able to be dragged to any state changing the text and css for that state.

Am also hoping that when it hits mobile, it becomes a basic slider with pre/next arrows.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the current code I am working with. 
http://jsfiddle.net/mRW7m/

```
    $(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
value:100,
min: 0,
max: 100,
step: 50,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
}
});
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});

<p>
<label for="amount">Donation amount ($50 increments):</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Right now it's incrementing on Value based, I am not sure how to change it to be different. I could set up three divs, and that way it can change out the divs??

Would it be best to say something like: when value = 0 then make visible div 0, and when value is 1, make visible div1 etc?

Comment: looks like you've found a starting point...time to start coding. come back when you hit a wall coding.

Comment: Ok I added some code to JS FIDDLE, will amend my original question.